# Disable lsp-mode for certain buffers matching a specific pattern

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, backup, c-mode

What's the preferred way to not enter lsp-mode for certain buffers such as Emacs' backup files named for instance, `app.c.~304fb1fe3650a354c4da16352f6c7be8bffd88cb~`.

I still want such files to open in `c-mode` or `c-ts-mode`.

Personally, I believe that backup files should not enter `lsp-mode` by default.

This is my attempt so far but it doesn't work:

```lisp
(defun lsp-disable-in-backup-buffer ()
  (let ((name (buffer-name)))
    (when (backup-file-name-p name)
      (lsp-mode -1)
      (message "Disabled `lsp-mode' in backup buffer %s"
               (faze name 'buffer)))))
(add-hook 'lsp-after-open-hook 'lsp-disable-in-backup-buffer)
```

Currently I'm enabling `lsp-mode` via the `prog-mode-hook` as

```lisp
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook (prog-mode . lsp-deferred)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't call lsp-deferred when the file is a backup file:

```lisp
(defun my-lsp-filter ()
  (unless (backup-file-name-p buffer-file-name)
    (lsp-deferred)))

(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook (prog-mode . my-lsp-filter))
```

I haven't tested it, but I guess this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```lisp
(defun lsp-disable-in-backup-buffer ()
  (let ((name (buffer-name)))
    (when (backup-file-name-p name)
      (lsp-mode -1)
      (message "Disabled `lsp-mode' in backup buffer %s"
               (faze name 'buffer)))))
(add-hook 'lsp-after-open-hook 'lsp-disable-in-backup-buffer)

Currently I'm enabling lsp-mode via the prog-mode-hook as

(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook (prog-mode . lsp-deferred)
)
```

suffices for now.

Comment: Wjhat's the difference between the code in the answer and the code in the question?